# RDP шлюз и ограничения на доменного пользователя

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server, rdp, hyper-v

У меня поднят сервер RDP на базе Windows server 2016 с помощью виртуальных машин Hyper-v. выделил специальную группу доменных пользователей для работы с коллекцией и все было бы хорошо, но возникла необходимость ограничить доступ определенных пользователей к другим машинам в домене кроме виртуальных. Как только я ввел ограничение доступ пользователя по списку доступных машин шлюз удаленных рабочих столов перестал пускать пользователя с ограничениями. Причем записей в журнале на шлюзе о неудачной авторизации я не нашел. При этом доступ к виртуальным машинам у пользователя есть (коннектился по RDP напрямую по ip машины), если отключить шлюз тоже все работает норм. Шлюз в списке доступных машин для пользователя прописан, в правилах шлюза эту группу доменных пользователей включил. Пробовал на тестовом пользователе добавить его в админы шлюза, пользователь все равно не проходит через шлюз, при этом на сам шлюз может приконектится по RDP. Что я упустил или сделал не так?

P.S. Пользователей действительно нужно ограничить, так как доверия личностям более чем на виртуалки нет, а шлюз нужен по ряду причин.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось проблема в самой сути списка компьютеров: он ограничивает не только компьютеры НА КОТОРЫЕ можно заходить, но и С КОТОРЫХ можно заходить.
пришлось все делать через разграничения групп, и удалить пользователей из группы Domain users (новая группа по умолчанию).